# Realtime API - how to render collaborative lists?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I've been trying recently to make a web app using Google Realtime API. However, I'm stuck on pretty basic things, while trying to implement collaborative lists. Here's a code example I've found (https://realtimeplayground.appspot.com/):

```js
var app = {};

function onInitialize (model) {
  var collaborativeList = model.createList();
  collaborativeList.pushAll(['Cat', 'Dog', 'Sheep', 'Chicken']);
  model.getRoot().set('demo_list', collaborativeList);
}

function onFileLoaded (doc) {
  app.doc = doc;
  app.listDemo = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('demo_list');
  setup();
}

function setup () {
  app.listDemo.addEventListener(
    gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_ADDED,
    onListChange);
  app.listDemo.addEventListener(
    gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_REMOVED,
    onListChange);
  app.listDemo.addEventListener(
    gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_SET,
    onListChange);
}

function onListChange (evt) {
  // Update the UI, etc.
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to bind those list elements to the DOM objects or even render them. Nothing I've tried so far seems to work. Can somebody tell me please how to connect those elements to the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could display the information from the collaborative list in a series of div elements. Let's say your html contained a div like this:

```
<div class='animal-list'></div>
```

Then you could define your event handler functions like this:

```
// add divs for the entries that are already in the list to begin with
function onFileLoaded (document) {
  // get the collaborative list
  var list = document.getModel().getRoot().get('demo_list');
  // get the div element containing the list
  var listElement = document.querySelector('.animal-list');
  // for each value in the list, create a div and insert into the list div
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // create the div element
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    // set the text to the animal name
    newElement.innerHTML = list.get(i);
    // append to the list div
    listElement.appendChild(newElement);
  }
  // call setup to add event handlers
  setup();
}

function setup () {
  // add different handler for each event type
  app.listDemo.addEventListener(
    gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_ADDED,
    onValuesAdded);
  app.listDemo.addEventListener(
    gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_REMOVED,
    onValuesRemoved);
  app.listDemo.addEventListener(
    gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_SET,
    onValuesSet);
}

// when values are added, add a div for each to the list div
function onValuesAdded(event) {
    // get the div element containing the list
    var listElement = document.querySelector('.animal-list');
    // beforeChild is false if we the values are at the end of the list,
    // otherwise, it is the child div that the new values will be inserted before
    var beforeChild = false;
    if (event.index < event.target.length) {
        beforeChild = listElement.childNodes[event.index];
    }
    // for each inserted value, create a div and insert into the list div
    for (var i = 0; i < event.values.length; i++) {
        // create the div element
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        // set the text to the animal name
        newElement.innerHTML = event.values[i];
        if (beforeChild) {
            // insert into the list div at the correct place
            listElement.insertBefore(listElement.childNodes[event.index]);
        } else {
            // append to the list div
            listElement.appendChild(newElement);
        }
    }
}

// remove the divs from the ui corresponding to the entries removed from the list
function onValuesRemoved(event) {
    // get the div element containing the list
    var listElement = document.querySelector('.animal-list');
    // remove the divs
    for (var i = 0; i < event.values.length; i++) {
         listElement.removeChild(listElement.childNodes[event.index]);
    }
}

function onValuesSet (evt) {
    // get the div element containing the list
    var listElement = document.querySelector('.animal-list');
    // for each set value, set the text of the div to the new value
    for (var i = 0; i < event.newValues.length; i++) {
        // set the text to the animal name
        listElement.childNodes[event.index + i].innerHTML = event.newValues[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer! Just one question, how to render the things from the list file at the start of the page? Cause, just by using EventListeners I can display them in a way you showed but it happens only when the event is triggered. What I need is to create corresponding DOM elements for the list elements that are already in the file when the file is loaded before a new value is set, removed or added by the user.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the answer to display the list elements that already exist on load

Answer (score 0):

The Realtime API handles all aspects of data transmission, storage, and conflict resolution when multiple users are editing a file. You may use '*gapi.drive.realtime.databinding*' for binding collaborative objects to UI elements.

You can start the Realtime API with this call: *gapi.drive.realtime.load(fileId, onFileLoaded, opt_initializerFn, opt_errorFn);*

'*onFileLoaded*' can be used to connect any user interface elements to collaborative entities in the model.

Here's a link for Official Google Documentation for Realtime API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.databinding

Link below is a sample project for Realtime API: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/google-drive-realtime-api/google-drive-realtime-api.d.ts